# I am getting the error while running the script for the default magento checkout

Tags: jmeter

The rest of the script is working properly but on checkout getting 403 / 404 error. I am not getting why it is happening. Do i need to pass cookies or session Id to get successful checkout or what can I do. please suggest in brief.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get "green" result and HTTP Response code 200 it doesn't guarantee that your test is doing what it is supposed to do, add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect response details starting from login, I think your test even doesn't perform a successful login.

So a couple of general recommendations:

1. Always add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Magento uses some form of CSRF Protection so you will need to get `form_key` parameter form the previous response and add it to the next request. See the following reference material for more information:

   - [Magento CSRF attack: A Simple Explanation](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/magento-csrf-attack-explanation/)
   - [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)

Comment: Thanks for help, can you guide me on how can i check response details whether my script had successfully performed login or not

Comment: Use "Response Data" tab of the [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree). For deep dive see [JMeter Error Checking and Dynamic Requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-training/jmeter-error-checking-and-dynamic-requests)

Comment: Thanks for headsup